# Best way to link images to text so that localization keeps things spaced properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, interface-builder

I've got an app with a big 'help' page that describes how to use it.  This page features a lot of text with some embedded images.  Is there some way to 'link' or attach these images to the bottom of specific text boxes so things will lay out reasonably well for any localization we do?  In other words, if the French translation of a block of text ends up being two lines longer than the English equivalent, I'd like the image that's placed below that text to be pushed downward by the appropriate amount without having to re-edit the layout of of the .xib file manually.  Possible?

Comment: You can make HTML page. You can place any thing after your text and can do modification. As it is HTML page it can easily wrap and auto adjust itself.
And show the html page in your webview by saving the HTML page in your local data

Comment: Ah, good idea.  Having a hard time finding good examples of this out there on the web (suggestions welcome :-) but I'm sure I can figure it out...  Also I'm not sure how to mark this question as 'answered' - is that because this was left as a comment instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make HTML page. You can place any thing after your text and can do modification. As it is HTML page it can easily wrap and auto adjust itself. And show the html page in your webview by saving the HTML page in your local data storage